# Dart Future functions with callbacks on requests

Tags: asynchronous, dart, future

I have an issue with understanding Future functions in dart and async programming. The examples I've found in web do not answer my question, so I would be grateful for community help.

I have a function that asks for players messages list:

```
Future getMessagesInfo(response) async{
        dialogs = []; // I need this list to be filled to proceed
        messagesList = response["data"];
        await getDialogsFunc(messagesList);
        renderMessages();
    }
```

It is a callback for a previous request, which doesn't really matters here. 
So, here is getDialogsFunc, which purpose is to runs through the list and ask playerInfo for each ID in the response:

```
Future getDialogsFunc(messagesList) async{
        for(var i=0;i<messagesList.length;i++){
            if(messagesList[i]["player2"] != player.ID)  await rm.getDialogInfo(messagesList[i]["player2"]);
            if(messagesList[i]["player1"] != player.ID)  await rm.getDialogInfo(messagesList[i]["player1"]);
        }
    }
```

Here is getDialogInfo, which actually sends a request for playerInfo and has a callback function that handles received info:

```
Future getDialogInfo(int id) async{
        messages = querySelector("account-messages-tab");
        var request = new Request();
        Object data = {"id": ServerAPI.PLAYER_INFO, "data":{"id": id}};
        await request.sendRequest(data,false, messages.onGotDialogInfo);
    }
```

The request is a simple class, that handles the requests:

```
class Request{
    Future sendRequest(Object data, bool action,Function callback) async{
        HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
        String url = "http://example.com";
        await request
            ..open('POST', url)
            ..onLoadEnd.listen((e)=> callback(JSON.decode(request.responseText)))
            ..send(JSON.encode(data));
    }
}
```

And finally here is a callback for the request:

```
Future onGotDialogInfo(response) async{
        List dialog = new List();
        dialog.add(response["data"]["id"]);
        dialog.add(response["data"]["login"]);
        dialogs.add(dialog);
 }
```

In the first function I wanted to run `renderMessages()` after I have received information about all messages, so that `dialogs` List should contain relevant information. In my realisation which I tested with breakpoints the `renderMessages()` functions runs BEFORE `onGotDialogInfo` callback.

What should I do to wait for the whole cycle `getDialogsFunc` functions and only then go to `renderMessages()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`whenComplete` is like `finally`, it's called no matter whether the request returned normally or with an error. Normally `then` is used.

`getDialogsFunc` uses `async` but doesn't use `await` which is a bit uncommon. This might be your intention, but I'm not sure

```
Future getDialogsFunc(messagesList) async {
    for(var i=0;i<messagesList.length;i++){
        if(messagesList[i]["player2"] != player.ID)  
          await rm.getDialogInfo(messagesList[i]["player2"]);
        if(messagesList[i]["player1"] != player.ID)
         await rm.getDialogInfo(messagesList[i]["player1"]);
    }
}
```

`getMessagesInfo` could then look like:

```
void getMessagesInfo(response) await {
    dialogs = []; // I need this list to be filled to proceed
    messagesList = response["data"];
    await getDialogsFunc(messagesList)
    renderMessages(messagesList);
}
```

I don't know where `Request` comes from, therefore hard to tell how that code should look like. It should at least use `await` for other `await`s to work as expected.

```
Future getDialogInfo(int id) async {
    messages = querySelector("account-messages-tab");
    var request = new Request();
    Object data = {"id": ServerAPI.PLAYER_INFO, "data":{"id": id}};
    final response = await request.sendRequest(data,false);
    messages.onGotDialogInfo(response)
}
```

**update**

```
class Request{
    Future sendRequest(Object data, bool action) async{
        Completer completer = new Completer();
        HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
        String url = "http://example.com";
        await request
            ..open('POST', url)
            ..onLoadEnd.listen((_) { 
               if (request.readyState == HttpRequest.DONE) {
                 if (request.status == 200) {
                   // data saved OK.
                   completer.complete(JSON.decode(request.responseText)); // output the response from the server
                 } else {
                   completer.completeError(request.status);
                 }
               }
            })
            ..send(JSON.encode(data));

        return completer.future;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello! Many thanks for the reply. I've edited the code according to your comments, but still it's not working as expected. The request class is simple:

`class Request{
 Future sendRequest(Object data, bool action,Function callback) async{
  HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
  String url = "http://example.com";
  await request
   ..open('POST', url)
   ..onLoadEnd.listen((e)=> callback(JSON.decode(request.responseText)))
   ..send(JSON.encode(data));
 }
}`

Comment: Hard to tell. "it's not working" is not too helpful. Please edit your question and post the code for `Request` there. Code in comments is unreadable.

Comment: I've edited the code with all corrections and added a request class code.

Comment: I updated my answer. I also changed the last 2 lines in `getDialogInfo()`

Comment: At the moment I've faced the problem that `response` is `"An instance of _Future"` and I can't get actual values.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the last line in `sendRequest` - updated.

Comment: Did it help? . . . .